# Swagger - Setting Default media-type or Accept Header for responses

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I'm setting my API to produce both JSON And XML for POST requests, with this spring boot code:

```
@PostMapping(
    consumes = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE },
    produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE }
)
public Game create(
        @Valid @RequestBody Game request,
        BindingResult bindingResult
) .../
```

This is working fine, and I can select either JSON or XML as the `media-type` in Swagger, but I want the **default** field to be JSON - at the moment it is **always** XML:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you use Springfox or Springdoc?

Comment: @helen I'm using SpringFox - looks as though I can't change the default with this framework?

Comment: Looks like should be possible in Springfox 3.0 by changing Docket configuration - see https://github.com/springfox/springfox/pull/3063

Answer (score 7):

Add the following property to `application.properties`:

```
springdoc.default-produces-media-type=application/json
```

For reference: [springdoc.org](https://springdoc.org/core-properties.html)

EDIT:

This solution is only applicable to [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/) java library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I'm actually using Springfox I have realised... but looks like I can't change it with that framework.... see https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/4030